# Lemma 2.3., Chapter 3 - Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: manifolds, proof-explanation, geodesic

A question about the lemma below

> Lemma 2.3. There exists a unique vector field $G$ on $TM$ whose trajectories are of the form $t \to (\gamma(t),\gamma'(t))$ where $\gamma$ is a geodesic on $M$.

Proof:

> We shall first prove the uniquiness of $G$, supposing its existence. Consider a system of coordinates $(U,x)$ on $M$. From the hypothesis, the trajectories of $G$ on $TU$ are given by $t \to (\gamma(t),\gamma'(t))$ where $\gamma$ is a geodesic. It follows that $t \to (\gamma(t),\gamma'(t))$ is a solution of the system of differential equations (1'). From the uniqueness of the trajectories of such system, we conclude that if $G$ exists, then it is unique. To prove the existence of $G$, define it locally by the system (1'). Using the uniqueness, we conclude that $G$ is well-defined on $TM$.

If you need I can write the system of ODE, but I don't think it's relevant.

What it seems to me is that the author from one side proves the uniqueness assuming existence, and later it defines the $G$ by the mentioned system of ODE and from there we know that the solution is unique.

Couldn't the author just skip the first part and move on with the definition using the system of ODE?

Comment: I don't know the logic line of the book in question. Seemingly, the author first defined the concept of geodesics for Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$, and then he defined the geodesic spray (i.e. the vector field in question), as the lemma you have quoted (in some highbrow terms, it is the infinitesimal generator of the geodesic flow). The problem about ODEs is that they depend on the choice of local coordinates, and one needs to check the independence with respect to coordinate transforms. Usually one prefers to define the concepts without such a choice, however this depends on personal taste.

Comment: Could you expand your comment a bit more in a full answer?

Comment: I am not doing this branch of mathematics and my understanding might be misleading. In short, what I wanted to say is that, philosophically one usually prefers to give coordinate-free definitions and then prove theorems or compute things with aids of a choice of coordinates whenever it helps. However maybe it is better for you to read more books to see whether most differential geometers prefer to work in this way.

Comment: By the way, technically, the argument you quoted on the uniqueness does **not** depend on the existence. `supposing its existence` is more a comment than a logical necessity. If we encode the uniqueness formally, it looks like for all $x_1$ and $x_2$, $P(x_1)\land P(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$. When we take $x_1,x_2$ to prove the uniqueness, logically we don't need to assume even an $x$ exists.